# Is it a method or a constructor?

Tags: java

i am a little comfused as to if the ex below is a constructor or a method. i know that constructor has the same name as a class  but it does not return anything.

```
public class Point3D {

    public Point3D transform(Matrix m){
```

Comment: it's method for me, constructor is a method which its name is as same as class name

Comment: Go and study some book in Java first !

Answer (score 6):

It is a method which returns instance of the same class `Point3D`. It appears that the method after accepting a parameter is returning an instance of the same class after transforming it.

See: [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

> Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that
>   they use the name of the class and have no return type.

Comment: A constructor would look like a methods with the same name as the class and no return type.